# Add @QueryParam to JAX-RS existing API in a backward compatible way for JerseyClient

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-client

I have an existing API.

```
@Api
@Path("/resourceA/v1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface ResourceA
{
    @GET
    @Path("{id : .+}")
    getResourceById(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

We have a requirement to add a new optional parameters (with `@QueryParam`) to that API, but we don't want to break existing Jersey client that uses this java interface to call our resource. **We can't simply add the `@QueryParam` to the existing method** as this would break backward compatibility and we still want our existing clients to work as before, only some of them needs the new parameter.

So far I have tried:

**Method 1**: use default implementation on the interface. This fails on the client as the jersey client uses a proxy object with method interceptor and this not play nicely with the `default` implementation for interface.

```
@Api
@Path("/resourceA/v1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface ResourceA
{

    default getResourceById(@PathParam("id") String id) 
    {
        return getResourceById(id, null);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id : .+}")
    getResourceById(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("param") String param);
}
```

**Method 2**: Add an overload of the method `getResourceById`. Then on the server side where I implement the methods, I manage the overload. This does not throw any error, but I have an indeterministic behavior on the server side, that sometimes, it calls the method without the `param` sometime it does not, independently if the `param` is present in the URL.

```
@Api
@Path("/resourceA/v1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface ResourceA
{
    @GET
    @Path("{id : .+}")
    getResourceById(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @GET
    @Path("{id : .+}")
    getResourceById(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("param") String param);
}
```

I wonder if JAX-RS has a best practice approach for this type of modification?

Thanks.